# Relation between causal mediation model and regular GLM in R

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, mediation

In the vignette for the 'mediation' R package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mediation/vignettes/mediation.pdf), the authors state that when "the outcome is binary all estimated effects are expressed as the increase
in probability" of the outcome. So the total effect of 0.07447 below indicates that compared to untreated, treatment increases the probability of the outcome by 7.4%.

When I run GLM, however, the estimate does not mirror the total effect from this causal mediation analysis. THe estimate is 0.4690. Exponentiation gives an OR of 1.33, which means that a 33% increase chance of the outcome is attributable to treatment compared to no treatment.

Why does the total effect of treatment in causal mediation analysis not correspond to the total effect in a logistic regression?

Note: the original example from the vignette uses the probit link function. I tried this all with probit regression and still see major differences.

````
data(framing)
med.fit <- lm(emo ~ treat + age + educ + gender + income, data=framing)
out.fit <- glm(cong_mesg ~ emo * treat + age + educ + gender + income, data = framing, family = binomial("logit"))
set.seed(2020)
med.out <- mediate(med.fit, out.fit, treat = "treat", mediator = "emo", robustSE = TRUE, sims = 100)
summary(med.out)

Causal Mediation Analysis 

Quasi-Bayesian Confidence Intervals

                          Estimate 95% CI Lower 95% CI Upper p-value    
ACME (control)             0.07212      0.01397         0.13  <2e-16 ***
ACME (treated)             0.09061      0.02375         0.15  <2e-16 ***
ADE (control)             -0.01614     -0.09799         0.08    0.78    
ADE (treated)              0.00235     -0.09703         0.12    0.98    
Total Effect               0.07447     -0.02624         0.19    0.28    
Prop. Mediated (control)   0.73903    -19.68185         4.33    0.28    
Prop. Mediated (treated)   0.94906    -19.06152         4.79    0.28    
ACME (average)             0.08136      0.02241         0.14  <2e-16 ***
ADE (average)             -0.00689     -0.10294         0.09    0.96    
Prop. Mediated (average)   0.84404    -17.82926         4.55    0.28    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Sample Size Used: 265 


Simulations: 100 

model <- glm(cong_mesg ~ treat, family = binomial(link = "logit"),data=framing)
summary(model)

Call:
glm(formula = cong_mesg ~ treat, family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
    data = framing)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.0302  -0.8523  -0.8523   1.3321   1.5420  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  -0.8256     0.1548  -5.333 9.65e-08 ***
treat         0.4690     0.2910   1.612    0.107    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 336.89  on 264  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 334.33  on 263  degrees of freedom
AIC: 338.33

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4

```
````

Answer (score 2):

Having the same question and problems as you, I eventually came across the `medflex` R package, which will give estimated causal effects in the form of log odds, with a detailed [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/medflex/vignettes/medflex.pdf) that also explains the limitation of the `mediation` package returning difficult to interpret effect sizes with binary outcomes that cannot be easily translated to odds ratios.

Based on my reading of the vignette, I would do the following for your example:

```
library(medflex)
library(mediation) # needed for the 'framing' dataset
data(framing)

expData <- neImpute(cong_mesg ~ treat + emo + age + educ + gender + income, 
                    family = binomial("logit"), data = framing)
nMod <- neModel(cong_mesg ~ treat0 + treat1 + age + educ + gender + income, 
                family = binomial("logit"), expData = expData)
summary(nMod)
```

```
# Natural effect model
# with standard errors based on the non-parametric bootstrap
# ---
# Exposure: treat
# Mediator(s): emo
# ---
# Parameter estimates:
#                                  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
# (Intercept)                     -1.064196   0.782587  -1.360  0.17388
# treat0                           0.064906   0.306860   0.212  0.83249
# treat1                           0.441412   0.143203   3.082  0.00205 **
# age                              0.008541   0.009180   0.930  0.35216
# educhigh school                 -0.598629   0.540590  -1.107  0.26814
# educsome college                -1.396218   0.577394  -2.418  0.01560 *
# educbachelor's degree or higher -1.414654   0.585492  -2.416  0.01568 *
# genderfemale                    -0.606781   0.306352  -1.981  0.04763 *
# income                           0.101512   0.038628   2.628  0.00859 **
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Here, the estimate for `treat0` is the log odds for the direct effect (analogous to the ADE) and the estimate for `treat1` is the log odds for the indirect effect (analogous to the ACME). So, the Odds Ratio for the indirect causal effect (ACME) of 'treat' through 'emo' is `exp(0.441412) = 1.55`, while the Odds Ratio for the direct effect (ADE) of 'treat' is `exp(0.064906) = 1.067`. The Odds Ratio for the total effect, assuming no iteraction between 'treat' and 'emo', is the sum of the two: `exp(0.064906 + 0.441412) = 1.66`

Comment: I'll leave the bounty open in case anyone has a better explanation or in case I'm totally wrong here